# Start programme on startup, but only when on laptop power

Tags: windows, boot, script

I have a programme called rainmeter which displays the time and date the second monitor i have plugged into my laptop which currently just runs on startup, but when I unplug my laptop and go to uni when I boot up I would prefer it if Rainmeter didnt just load up as I have to close it every single time. I've seen previously on windows 8 someone wrote a script that achieved this but it doesnt seem to work in windows 10. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you use Task Schedule to launch Rainmeter at login then there is an option "start the task only if the computer is on AC power".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a battery, so this answer is written blindly,
based on the article
[How Can I Tell Whether a Laptop Computer is Running Off Batteries?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-laptop-computer-is-running-off-batteries/)

Create a file named, say, `test.vbs` and containing the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell :Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim objWMIService :Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\wmi")
Dim colItems :Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From BatteryStatus Where Voltage > 0")
Dim objItem :Set objItem = Nothing

For Each objItem in colItems
    If (objItem.PowerOnline = "True") Then objShell.Run "C:\Windows\notepad.exe"
Next
```

Run this file with and without AC power, to see if `notepad`
is started only on AC power.

If the script fails, please let me know the error.

If the script succeeds, you may replace `notepad` with
the full path to `rainmeter`
and have it run on login by placing it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

---

Note: If the path to the executable contains spaces,
the command needs to be written like this:

```
objShell.Run("""c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe""")
```

Or like this:

```
objShell.Exec("c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
```

See the post
[Launch programs whose path contains spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340355/launch-programs-whose-path-contains-spaces).

Comment: It works, but not with any programme in programme files (x86), it comes up with this error. The file path is correct and it works with other exe's in the windows folder for example I got it to open file explorer, but it wont open Rainmeter because it cant find the file. (and ive double and triple checked there was nothing wrong with the file path i gave it)

Comment: I understand then that the battery test works, which is already a big step forward. For the rest, see my addition to the answer.

Comment: Marvelous its worked now thank you